# Generating pure virtual functions and implementations from type list

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Let's imagine simple typelist:

```
template<typename...Types>
struct TypeList
{}
```

I would like to use such typelist to generate N virtual functions in single interface for each type, and generate N implementations of that also in single impl type, which can decay to interface.

My attempt:

```
template<typename Type>
struct Itf_SingleType
{
    virtual void process(const Type&) = 0;
};

template<typename...>
struct Itf;

template<typename...Types>
struct Itf<TypeList<Types...>> : Itf_SingleType<Types>...
{
    using Itf_SingleType<Types>::process...;
    virtual ~Itf() = default;
};
```

At this point I have N virtual functions in interface. But I have problem with attaching implementations:

```
template<typename Type>
struct Impl_SingleType
{
   void process(const Type&)
   {
        //can be anything at this point, so let it be this:
        puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
   }
};

template<typename...>
struct Impl;

template<typename...Types>
struct Impl<TypeList<Types...>> : Itf<TypeList<Types...>>, Impl_SingleType<Types>...
{
    using Impl_SingleType<Types>::process...;
};
```

Wandbox with example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/s0n1DX7t7we8d6mM

However I still get two errors:

1. <del>Dunno why it cannot choose between `process(const int&)` and `process(const std::string&)` with `process(7)`.</del> fixed by adding `using Itf_SingleType<Types>::process...;` to `Itf`
2. Dunno why it still think it's not overloaded despite `using` declaration inside `Impl`

We can assume C++17 support.

Comment: We cannot override by sibling classes. Is virtual inheritance ok [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b7620c32ca17db8)?

Answer (score 1):

`Itf_SingleType::process` doesn't override `Itf_SingleType::process` because the two classes are unrelated. A class that inherits from both will simply have two different unrelated functions named `process` with the same signature. Here is how you can fix that:

```
template<typename...Types>
struct Itf<TypeList<Types...>> : virtual Itf_SingleType<Types>... // virtual!
...

template<typename Type>
struct Impl_SingleType : virtual Itf_SingleType<Type> // <- virtual!
{
   void process(const Type&) override // now we override
   {
   }
};
```

Comment: We might notice in OP's link the error about `Impl<ExampleTypeList>` still abstract.

Answer (score 0):

> If some member function `vf` is declared as *virtual* in a class `Base`, and some class `Derived`, which is derived, directly or indirectly, from `Base`, has a declaration for member function with the same
>
> 1. name
> 2. parameter type list (but not the return type)
> 3. cv-qualifiers
> 4. ref-qualifiers
>
> Then this function in the class `Derived` is also *virtual* (whether or not the keyword `virtual` is used in its declaration) and *overrides* `Base::vf` (whether or not the word `override` is used in its declaration).

> A virtual member function `vf` of a base class `Base` is the ***final overrider*** unless the derived class declares or inherits (through multiple inheritance) another function that overrides `vf`.

> An *abstract class* is a class that either defines or inherits at least one function for which the ***final overrider*** is *pure virtual*.

Factly, `Impl` is an abstract class because its ***final overriders*** of `process` are still *pure virtual*. (`process` I mentioned means any instantiations of `process<T>`.)

why? because `Impl_SingleType` doesn't inherit `Itf_SingleType`, so `Impl_SingleType::process` doesn't override the pure virtual function declaration `Itf_SingleType::process`. so neither `Impl::process` (it doesn't exist) nor `Impl_SingleType::process` can override `Itf_SingleType::process`. the ***final overrider*** is actually `Itf_SingleType::process` itself!

so to let this code valid, you should let `Impl_SingleType` inherit `Itf_SingleType`.